# File can't be found in file DB

Tags: android, android-intent, xamarin

I am starting an intent to pick a file, I do pick a file and I get a `URI`, which I obviously can't use.

I am trying to convert this Uri to a legit file path and for that I use this method

```
    public string GetPathToImage(global::Android.Net.Uri uri)
    {
        string path = null;
        // The projection contains the columns we want to return in our query.
        string[] projection = new[] { global::Android.Provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.InterfaceConsts.Data };
        using (global::Android.Database.ICursor cursor = ManagedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null))
        {
            if (cursor != null)
            {
                int columnIndex = cursor.GetColumnIndexOrThrow(global::Android.Provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.InterfaceConsts.Data);
                cursor.MoveToFirst();
                path = cursor.GetString(columnIndex);
            }
        }
        return path;
    }
```

Problem: this method returns a `null` string. But I need a working one.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You should google for getrealpathfromuri.

Comment: @greenapps I tried. Unfortunately it ends here.

Comment: I see now that you need it for xamarin..... well no further comments ...